# Create a Single Boxplot from Multiple DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

I have multiple data frames with different no. of rows and same no.of columns i.e

#### DATA

```
female_df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [5,21,17], 'value': [85, 56.7, 77.9]})
female_df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [75,1,7], 'value': [39, 66.7, 77.9]})
female_df3 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [5,21,17], 'value': [85, 56.7, 77.9]})
female_df4 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [5,21,17], 'value': [85, 56.7, 77.9]})
male_df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [35,1,7], 'value': [15, 36.7, 87.9]})
male_df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [5,11,17], 'value': [99, 96.7, 97.9]})
male_df3 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [35,41,37], 'value': [15, 16.7, 17.9]})
male_df4 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [51,11,27], 'value': [35, 36.7, 37.9]})
```

Now, I would like to plot a single boxplot from above multiple df's. I used below code to do so

```
fig, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,10))
vec = [female_df1['value'].values,female_df2['value'].values,female_df3['value'].values,female_df4['value'].values]
labels = ['f1','f2','f3', 'f4']
ax2.boxplot(vec, labels = labels)
plt.show()
```

The Output in [female values boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpw8J.png), now similarly I have Male data frames with values, and I want to plot side by side (i.e fbeta1.0 and mbeta1.0) to observe the difference in data distribution. Valuable insights much appreciated

Desired Output plot:
[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT7dS.png)

Comment: Can you not update the `vec` to contain female_df1, male_df1, female_df2, male_df2,....?

Comment: yes I can but it is not shown a side-by-side plot

Comment: can you do a  `df.to_dict()` to help other reproduce the dataframes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit manual, but should do what you need...

```
### DATA ###
female_df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [5,21,17], 'value': [85, 56.7, 77.9]})
female_df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [75,1,7], 'value': [39, 66.7, 77.9]})
female_df3 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [5,21,17], 'value': [85, 56.7, 77.9]})
female_df4 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [5,21,17], 'value': [85, 56.7, 77.9]})
male_df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [35,1,7], 'value': [15, 36.7, 87.9]})
male_df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [5,11,17], 'value': [99, 96.7, 97.9]})
male_df3 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [35,41,37], 'value': [15, 16.7, 17.9]})
male_df4 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [51,11,27], 'value': [35, 36.7, 37.9]})

### PLOTTING ###
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,4, figsize = (15,6))
ax[0].boxplot([female_df1['value'].values, male_df1['value'].values], labels = ['f1','m1'])
ax[1].boxplot([female_df2['value'].values, male_df2['value'].values], labels = ['f1','m1'])
ax[2].boxplot([female_df3['value'].values, male_df3['value'].values], labels = ['f1','m1'])
ax[3].boxplot([female_df4['value'].values, male_df4['value'].values], labels = ['f1','m1'])

ax[0].set_title("M1 & F1")
ax[1].set_title("M2 & F2")
ax[2].set_title("M3 & F3")
ax[3].set_title("M4 & F4")
plt.show()
```

**Plot**

[image]